# What is the best way to send transform (with scale)?

Tags: ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I want to transform set of points according to formula s*R.dot(xyz) + t

Because of implementation details i want  to make multiplication s*R and send "scaled" rotation via /tf.

But while converting  "scaled" rotation (s*R) to quaternions i'm getting TF_DENORMALIZED_QUATERNION error
So, the question is: how to scale R properly? Or what is the best way to send transform with scale?
P.S. s  is a scalar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342629/what-is-the-best-way-to-send-transform-(with-scale)?/) by [Dmitry](https://answers.ros.org/users/50888/dmitry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-27**:
Have you tried renormalising the quaternion?

**Comment by [Dmitry](https://answers.ros.org/users/50888/dmitry/) on 2020-01-27**:
Oh, no. I'll try that. Thank you!

**Comment by [Dmitry](https://answers.ros.org/users/50888/dmitry/) on 2020-01-27**:
I did it.
After renormalizing (via `transformations.union_vector`) i'm getting wrong result when applying rotation.
For now, I decided to created new message type (StampedFloat) and send it separately from R and t transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot send non-normalized transforms (rotations or translations) via tf. It's designed to keep track of coordinate frames in space and apply transforms to data. A scaling operation is not generally applicable to transforming between coordinate frames where we keep all data in units of meters according to [REP 103](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html). So we limit the system to homogeneous transformations.

Since your scaling operation is semantically significant you should do that before or after you operate on the data and then make sure that the data is then observably different between the two states.

---

To your direct question if you want to send a transform with scale you can create a message to capture any sort of transform representation that you want and send it through a topic.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gbohus](https://answers.ros.org/users/58051/gbohus/) on 2021-07-21**:
Thanks for the clarification.
Just a small comment: in linear algebra "homogeneous" means mapping zero to zero. What you mean here is "unitary".